# Como puedo generar un id único con firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Hola tengo una inquietud con respecto a Firebase quiero generar un id cada vez que se genere un registro y lo requiero para antes de crear ese registro hay alguna propiedad de firebase para generarlo?

muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: firebase te genera un id único que maneja como uid, o a qué te refieres?

Comment: si pero no en todos los registros quiero generar algo parecido antes de insertar el registro o ya que evalué bien lo que quiero puede ser cuando se genere el registro

Answer (score 1):

Depende de que plataforma lo llames, pero el SDK en todas tiene la función [Push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push) , la cual genera nodo con un ID único para toda la base. De esa forma puedes crear el nodo con el ID único y luego meter el registro nuevo dentro de este.